# Why does adding zero change the result on wolframalpha? (i.e. A*B != A*B+0)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, wolfram-alpha

[exhibit A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B-V,0%5D,%5BU,0%5D%5D*inv(%5B%5B1,0%5D,%5B-rho,1%5D%5D)*%5B%5B-1,0%5D,%5B0,Y%5D%5D)

`[[-V,0],[U,0]]*inv([[1,0],[-rho,1]])*[[-1,0],[0,Y]]`

`=`

`[[V,0],[-U,0]]`

[exhibit B](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B-V,0%5D,%5BU,0%5D%5D*inv(%5B%5B1,0%5D,%5B-rho,1%5D%5D)*%5B%5B-1,0%5D,%5B0,Y%5D%5D%2B%5B%5B0,0%5D,%5B0,0%5D%5D)

`[[-V,0],[U,0]]*inv([[1,0],[-rho,1]])*[[-1,0],[0,Y]] + [[0,0],[0,0]]`

`=`

`[[V,0],[0,0]]`

but

`[[V,0],[-U,0]]` != `[[V,0],[0,0]]`

What gives?

Comment: You are correct to notice that something is wrong since adding the zero matrix should not change anything.  If you were to have typed it [like so](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-V,0%7D,%7BU,0%7D%7D*%7B%7B1,0%7D,%7B-rho,1%7D%7D%5E(-1)*%7B%7B-1,0%7D,%7B0,Y%7D%7D%2B%7B%7B0,0%7D,%7B0,0%7D%7D) the one on the right is again $\begin{bmatrix}V&0\\-U&0\end{bmatrix}$, so there is something off about using square brackets instead of braces to denote matrices.  In my experience, square brackets often denote arrays in mathematica instead of matrices.

Comment: As for specifically what operation it *thinks* it is carrying out and why the result has changed, I'm not sure.